# What is going on in this sentence from Noctes Atticae: 'quod eum comperissent argenti facti cenae gratia decem pondo libras habere.'?

Tags: latin-to-english-translation

The full sentence is:

> C. Fabricius Luscinus et Q. Aemilius Papus censores Romae fuerunt et P. Cornelium Rufinum, qui bis consul fuerat, senatu moverunt: causamque isti notae subscripserunt 'quod eum comperissent argenti facti cenae gratiā decem pondo libras habere.'

My translation is:

> C and Q, censors in Rome, ejected P - who had twice been consul and dictator - from the senate, and under the cause of which they wrote, noting: 'for they had discovered that he possessed via favouritism [dinnerware?] made of silver weighing ten pounds.''

Mainly I'm unclear about what 'notae' is doing (I am translating it as a participle of censores but since they are plural masculine I know that can't be correct) as well as 'cenae'. Can it here mean silverware? I thought it only referred to the meal itself. Also wondering if I'm understanding the ablative 'gratiā' correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- *isti notae* is dative indirect object of *subscripserunt*: 'under this note they wrote (as) the cause'. The note in question is the written record of censure explaining why he was expelled from the Senate. Cf. Livy 41.27 *de senatu novem eiecerunt; insignes notae fuerunt...* "they expelled nine men from the Senate; the important censures were those of..."
- *argentum factum* is 'wrought silver'; it is going with *decem libras* and with the ablative *pondo*: 'ten pounds by weight of wrought silver'.
- *[gratiā](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=gratia&la=la#lexicon)* here is functioning as a postposition with the genitive (like *[causā](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/morph?l=causa&la=la#lexicon)*), so *cenae gratiā* 'for / on account of dinner'.

I read *argenti facti cenae gratiā* as meaning silver plate or dinnerware, as you surmised. So the cause of his expulsion is that 'they had learned that he possessed ten pounds by weight of silver plate'.